# How do I delete till non-whitespace in vim?

Tags: vim, whitespace

I'm looking for a command to delete from the cursor to the first non-whitespace character on the same line. I've googled for a while and tried several possibilities. No joy. Does someone out there know how to do this?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The sequence <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> will delete all characters from the cursor until the next word. This means that if you execute the command while standing in the middle of a word, it will delete the remainder of that word and subsequent whitespaces. May or may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: This does it. It's a bit counterintuitive - I expected dw to mean "delete the current word, starting at the cursor". But it works, it works. Thanks.

Comment: Per the usual scheme, you can also do d2w, d3w et c to delete all characters until the second or third word after the cursor. If this answer solved your problem, please accept it as correct.

Comment: +1. To be precise, `w` means "move to the beginning of the next word", and `d<movement>` deletes from the current position to where the movement takes you.

Comment: to delete a word regardless on which letter the cursor is on, use `daw` (mnemonic "delete a word") works with other commands as well, e.g. `caw` "change a word"

Comment: `daw` appears to also remove a space before the word if one exists. A better combo to use is `diw` which is delete in word. It also works regardless of cursor position in the word.

Comment: What about more than one line? I know this is not the question, but something to go over multiple lines would be more useful.

Comment: @Zelphir I added an answer that shows how to do this over multiple lines.

Answer (score 25):

You may want to try <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>. This will move by "WORD" (see help for WORD and word), which looks more appropriate for your question.

The `dw` won't meet your needs in, for example:

```
array[1] = 5
```

Hitting `dw` while positioned in the `a` will leave you with:

```
[1] = 5
```

But using `dW` will result in:

```
= 5
```

Answer (score 25):

Many of the answers here don't really address the question directly. The asker wants to know how to delete up to the *first* ***non***-whitespace character. Some of the answers *will* technically work, but let's take a look at how to do this explicitly.

The following examples demonstrate how to do this in *normal* mode with variations that account for the starting position of the cursor. The u̲nderlined c̲haracters indicate the cursor position:

---

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>:  
foo_     bar
  →  
foob̲ar

The *<kbd>d</kbd>elete <kbd>w</kbd>ord* command, described in other answers, works just fine to delete up to the next non-whitespace character when our cursor is positioned *before* the target.

---

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>:  
foo      b̲ar 
  →   
b̲ar

Naturally, we'd want to try the inverse of <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> to delete *backwards* to the first non-whitespace character *before* the cursor. However, as shown above, the *<kbd>d</kbd>elete <kbd>b</kbd>ack-word* command deletes more than we expect—it erases the previous word as well. For this case, we should use:

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd><?></kbd>:   
foo      b̲ar
  →   
foob̲ar

...where <kbd><?></kbd> is the first non-whitespace character before the cursor. The *<kbd>d</kbd>elete back-un<kbd>T</kbd>il* command erases everything *up to but not including* the character <kbd><?></kbd>, which, in this case, is the character <kbd>o</kbd> at the end of "foo".

---

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd><?></kbd>:  
foo_     bar
  →  
foob̲ar

Similar to the previous command, we can use *<kbd>d</kbd>elete un<kbd>t</kbd>il* (with a lowercase "t") to delete characters *forward* until the next <kbd><?></kbd> character (the <kbd>b</kbd> in "bar", for this example). This achieves the same result as <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> for the purpose of this question.

---

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>:  
foo   _   bar
  →  
foob̲ar

If our cursor is positioned in the middle of the whitespace, we can use the *<kbd>d</kbd>elete <kbd>i</kbd>nner <kbd>w</kbd>ord* command to remove the whitespace from both sides.

---

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd><?></kbd><kbd>↵</kbd>:  
foo_   `\n`   bar
  →  
foob̲ar

If the whitespace we want to remove includes line-breaks, we can use the command shown above to *<kbd>d</kbd>elete until matched pattern of <kbd><?></kbd>*, where the *pattern* in this case is just the first non-whitespace character. As shown, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to complete this command.

When the first non-whitespace character occurs at the beginning of the line after the break, Vim will remove the whitespace, but leave the target on the next line. We need to add <kbd>J</kbd> to the above command to *<kbd>J</kbd>oin* the lines (an uppercase "j").

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd><?></kbd><kbd>↵</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>:  
foo_     `\n`bar
  →  
foob̲ar

Comment: Thank you for addressing the line-breaks! Your answer seems to say `<?>` is the pattern for matching the first non-whitespace character. However, I had to use `\S` for the pattern. My whole command was therefore `d/\S↵`. This may be what you meant in your answer, but it was not immediately clear to me.

Comment: @Micah Sorry for being unclear. I used `<?>` in this answer as a placeholder that represents _some character_. I intended for a reader to substitute `<?>` with a particular character in the edited text rather than to enter those keystrokes literally. For that last example, your choice to enter `\S` in place of pattern `<?>` does indeed produce the best generic command to remove white space across line breaks. I prefer to type the actual character (`b` in the example) because it's usually easier to reach for.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant this has saved me so much time !!!

Answer (score 7):

To delete a word regardless on which letter the cursor is on, use <kbd>daw</kbd> (mnemonic "delete a word") works with other commands as well, e.g. <kbd>caw</kbd> "change a word". <kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>t</kbd> are other excellent command that can be used together with <kbd>d</kbd>. E.g. to delete from cursor to and including first occurrence of e.g. the letter "t", use <kbd>dft</kbd>. To leave the "t" intact, use <kbd>dtt</kbd> instead.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> should work.

Answer (score 0):

`d` `W` will delete word include the last space. If the word you want to delete is at the end of a line, you can prefer use `d` `e`. because if you use `d` `W`, it can shift your next line up.

I always use `d` `i` `W`.